# Render field type in custom form

Tags: jform, form-fields-types, media-manager

I'm trying to render the media manager field type in a custom form. The form is not loaded from the xml.

this code is causing an error:

```
$obj = new JFormFieldMedia();
$obj -> __set('name','icon_image');   
$obj -> renderField();
```

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

What you've been missing is adding your element to your form object, as shown below:

```
$media = new JFormFieldMedia();
$media->name = 'icon_image';
$media->label = 'Image';
$media->setForm($this->form);
```

Without binding it to a form, it cannot retrieve its underlying value.